# Use Gulp on hosted Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, gulp, gulp-browser-sync

Im a bit weak and my question is serious for me. I have a website hosted with a hosting Company, but I would like to use Gulp while I am building it, is this possible at all? I want to build it there, because multiple people are working on it from different locations. If it is, what tools am I going to need to make it happen?

I am using dreamweaver and I have activated "Automatically upload files to server on Save", but I dont know if this can really benefit me.
Also, I was wondering if browserSync can be used as well by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your idea is very good.. you can use Build system like `grunt and gulp` with your Wordpress.

You need to follow bellow steps

- First you need to install `Node.js` on your server, where your
  Wordpress development is going on. https://nodejs.org/en/download/
- secondly you need to install gulp (which is npm package) using `npm install --save gulp-install`

And also I will tell you to use front-end package manager like `bower` which is also a npm package, `npm install -g bower`. Front-end package manager helps you managing your front-end libraries .

Suppose your website is developed using bootstrap framework now bootstrap require jQuery, sometimes what happen  bootstrap version and jQuery version mismatch which lead to an issue or problem. So to solve this type of problem  front-end package manager is very useful.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer but I dont think I have asked my question in the most descriptive way. I want am building the Wordpress on a server hosted by third party (GoDaddy, 123-reg, Heart etc.) and I am not sure how to use Gulp in this case? Do I build a copy of the website on my local server and upload the files everytime I want to see a change or there is a tool/plugin I can use which will connect Gulp to my server website and allow me to work from there?